How to add a "File upload" to a google forms with Google apps script?
I am uploading the Excel file to Google Drive via Apps Script. There are questions in Excel. The questions are transferred to Google Form, but some questions require image upload. I do not know how to upload photos via Apps Script in Google Form.
// Entry point for HTTP GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle('Excel Dosyası Yükle');
}

// Function to handle file upload
function uploadFile(data, fileName) {
  try {
    // Decode base64 data
    const contentType = data.match(/^data:(.*);base64,/)[1];
    const bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.split(',')[1]);
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, fileName);

    // Upload to Google Drive and convert to Google Sheets format
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1MyMpYut-v4IlU-JM1wL96CFV-q6TjaiQ');
    const file = folder.createFile(blob);

    const resource = {
      title: fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      parents: [{ id: '1MyMpYut-v4IlU-JM1wL96CFV-q6TjaiQ' }]
    };

    const spreadsheetFile = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId(), { convert: true });
    file.setTrashed(true);

    // Work with the spreadsheet
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetFile.id);
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    const b2Value = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
    const b4Value = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
    sheet.getRange('E6').setValue('FOTOĞRAF');
    const formattedDate = formatDate(b4Value);
    const newFileName = `${b2Value} ${formattedDate} TARİHLİ DENETİM`;
    DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetFile.id).setName(newFileName);

    // Perform VLOOKUP-like operation
    performVlookupAndFill(sheet);

    // Create and populate the Google Form
    const formId = createAndPopulateForm(sheet, b2Value, formattedDate);
    const formUrl = `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/${formId}`;
    const formPreviewUrl = `${formUrl}/viewform`;

    // Update linked spreadsheet
    updateLinkedSpreadsheet(b2Value, formattedDate, spreadsheetFile.id, formPreviewUrl);

    return { message: `Dosya başarıyla yüklendi ve dönüştürüldü: ${newFileName}` };
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + error.toString());
    return { message: 'Hata: ' + error.toString() };
  }
}

// Helper function to format date
function formatDate(date) {
  const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  const month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
}

// Helper function to create and populate a Google Form
function createAndPopulateForm(sheet, b2Value, formattedDate) {
  const form = FormApp.create(`${b2Value} ${formattedDate} TARİHLİ DENETİM`);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1NHM5HziCLNE9nlCt5RmlpCQ5w9pbQLrt');
  folder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId()));

  const questions = sheet.getRange('C7:C').getValues().flat();
  const helpTexts = sheet.getRange('B7:B').getValues().flat();
  const responses = sheet.getRange('E7:E').getValues().flat();

  questions.forEach((question, index) => {
    if (question) {
      form.addParagraphTextItem()
        .setTitle(question)
        .setHelpText(helpTexts[index] || '')
        .setRequired(true);
    }
  });

  const fileId = '150wswiya4QP244Sjf4QlKmNFISxDrpfy'; // Yüklenecek dosyanın ID'si

  responses.forEach((response, index) => {
    if (response.toString().toUpperCase() === 'EVET') {
      const item = form.addFileUploadItem().setTitle('Fotoğraf Yükle ' + (index + 1));
      item.asFileUploadItem().createResponse(fileId);
    }
  });

  return form.getId();
}

// Helper function to update the linked spreadsheet
function updateLinkedSpreadsheet(b2Value, formattedDate, spreadsheetId, formPreviewUrl) {
  const linkedSpreadsheetId = '1m7rJndo3jRcVhPC04rb_Zas6NFawQOFhpoQY8yqJb2Y';
  const linkedSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(linkedSpreadsheetId);
  const linkedSheet = linkedSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  const lastRow = linkedSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  linkedSheet.getRange(`A${lastRow}`).setValue(b2Value);
  linkedSheet.getRange(`B${lastRow}`).setValue(formattedDate);
  linkedSheet.getRange(`C${lastRow}`).setValue('YÜKLENDİ');
  linkedSheet.getRange(`D${lastRow}`).setValue(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}`);
  linkedSheet.getRange(`E${lastRow}`).setValue(formPreviewUrl);
}

// Helper function to perform VLOOKUP-like operation and fill in values
function performVlookupAndFill(sheet) {
  const linkedSpreadsheetId = '1m7rJndo3jRcVhPC04rb_Zas6NFawQOFhpoQY8yqJb2Y';
  const linkedSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(linkedSpreadsheetId);
  const subeSheet = linkedSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("SUBE");

  const subeAValues = subeSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();
  const subeBValues = subeSheet.getRange('B2:B').getValues().flat();
  const cValues = sheet.getRange('C7:C').getValues().flat();

  const eValues = cValues.map(value => {
    return [vlookupCaseInsensitive(value, subeAValues, subeBValues)];
  });

  sheet.getRange(7, 5, eValues.length, 1).setValues(eValues);
}

// Helper function to perform case-insensitive VLOOKUP
function vlookupCaseInsensitive(searchValue, searchRange, resultRange) {
  searchValue = searchValue.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < searchRange.length; i++) {
    if (searchRange[i].toString().trim().toLowerCase() === searchValue) {
      return resultRange[i];
    }
  }
  return '';
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Excel Dosyası Yükle</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    @media (max-width: 576px) {
      .custom-container {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
      }
    }
    .spinner-overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      z-index: 9999;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .spinner {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
      border-radius: 50%;
      animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 custom-container">
        <div class="card shadow">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-4">Excel Dosyası Yükle</h1>
            <form id="uploadForm">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="excelFile" class="form-label">Excel Dosyası Seç</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="excelFile" accept=".xls,.xlsx" required>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Yükle</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="statusModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="statusModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="statusModalLabel">Durum</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="status"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Tamam</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('uploadForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const fileInput = document.getElementById('excelFile');
      const file = fileInput.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const spinnerOverlay = document.createElement('div');
      spinnerOverlay.classList.add('spinner-overlay');
      const spinner = document.createElement('div');
      spinner.classList.add('spinner');
      spinner.setAttribute('role', 'status');
      spinner.innerHTML = '<span class="visually-hidden">Yükleniyor...</span>';
      spinnerOverlay.appendChild(spinner);
      document.body.appendChild(spinnerOverlay);

      reader.onload = function (event) {
        const data = event.target.result;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (response) {
          const statusModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('statusModal'));
          document.getElementById('status').innerText = response.message;
          statusModal.show();
          fileInput.value = '';
          spinnerOverlay.remove();
        }).withFailureHandler(function (error) {
          const statusModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('statusModal'));
          document.getElementById('status').innerText = 'Dosya yüklenirken bir hata oluştu: ' + error.message;
          statusModal.show();
          spinnerOverlay.remove();
        }).uploadFile(data, file.name);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I upload the excel file from index.html, the excel file turns into tables on Google, then there are questions in Excel, these questions are transferred to Google form, some questions require photos, but I don't know how to add photos in Google form.

The question needs more focus and clarity. Questions on this site should be about a specific programming problem. Please don't include the whole project code, instead create a [mcve] focused on the specific problem to solve. In this case, it's not clear if you are looking to upload images or to add a file upload item so the form respondent can upload images.

There are questions in excel files, these questions are transferred to Google form, but some questions require photo software. I want to add an upload file with appscript.
How to add a "File upload question" to a forms with Google apps script?

As of June 2024, it's not possible. On the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker, a feature request asks to add this feature. Please star it.
Support the File Upload question type in FormsApp
From Forms Service, the following are the available item types that could be used to create items (including questions).



Name
Brief Description




DateItem
A question item that allows the respondent to indicate a date.


DateTimeItem
A question item that allows the respondent to indicate a date and time.


DurationItem
A question item that allows the respondent to indicate a length of time.


GridItem
A question item, presented as a grid of columns and rows, that allows the respondent to select one choice per row from a sequence of radio buttons.


ImageItem
A layout item that displays an image.


ListItem
A question item that allows the respondent to select one choice from a drop-down list.


MultipleChoiceItem
A question item that allows the respondent to select one choice from a list of radio buttons or an optional "other" field.


PageBreakItem
A layout item that marks the start of a page.


ParagraphTextItem
A question item that allows the respondent to enter a block of text.


ScaleItem
A question item that allows the respondent to choose one option from a numbered sequence of radio buttons.


SectionHeaderItem
A layout item that visually indicates the start of a section.


TextItem
A question item that allows the respondent to enter a single line of text.


TimeItem
A question item that allows the respondent to indicate a time of day.


VideoItem
A layout item that displays a video.



Related

How to add a "File upload question" to a forms with Google apps script?


Expanding on the above: even if one were to open the Form and manually create a prefill link, the prefill-process will not save any proposed file name, and the link itself doesn't include any provision for a file name.
